# How to crop and zoom an image with react-image-crop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to be able to zoom and crop an image like in react-easy-crop but with react-image-crop

so far it cuts me off but when I zoom using ReactCrop's scale = prop

Doesn't take this into account for clipping

I need to zoom to the photo and crop it with the canvas this is my canvas code with which I crop the photo

```
     const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

  const scaleX: number = image.naturalWidth / image.width
  const scaleY: number = image.naturalHeight / image.height

  canvas.width = crop.width
  canvas.height = crop.height

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  // New lines to be added
  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio

  canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio
  canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio

  if (ctx !== null) {
    ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0)
    ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'

    ctx.drawImage(
      image,
      crop.x * scaleX,
      crop.y * scaleY,
      crop.width * scaleX,
      crop.height * scaleY,
      0,
      0,
      crop.width,
      crop.height
    )
  }

  // As Base64 string
  // const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
  // return base64Image;

  // As a blob
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    canvas.toBlob(
      (blob: any) => {
        if (blob) {
          blob.name = fileName
          const newImg = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
          resolve(newImg)
        }
        return
      },
      'image/png',
      1
    )
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

By passign scale and rotate argument you will have exact image that you cropped.

```
function getCroppedImg(
  image: HTMLImageElement, // useRef reference
  crop: PixelCrop,
  scale = 1,
  rotate = 0
) {

  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = crop.width;
  canvas.height = crop.height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!ctx) {
    throw new Error('No 2d context');
  }

  const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
  const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
  // devicePixelRatio slightly increases sharpness on retina devices
  // at the expense of slightly slower render times and needing to
  // size the image back down if you want to download/upload and be
  // true to the images natural size.
  const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
  // const pixelRatio = 1

  canvas.width = Math.floor(crop.width * scaleX * pixelRatio);
  canvas.height = Math.floor(crop.height * scaleY * pixelRatio);

  ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio); // this line will handle the scale or zoom image
  ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';

  const cropX = crop.x * scaleX;
  const cropY = crop.y * scaleY;

  const rotateRads = rotate * TO_RADIANS; // this line will handle the rotation of image
  const centerX = image.naturalWidth / 2;
  const centerY = image.naturalHeight / 2;

  ctx.save();

  // 5) Move the crop origin to the canvas origin (0,0)
  ctx.translate(-cropX, -cropY);
  // 4) Move the origin to the center of the original position
  ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
  // 3) Rotate around the origin
  ctx.rotate(rotateRads);
  // 2) Scale the image
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  // 1) Move the center of the image to the origin (0,0)
  ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY);

  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, image.naturalWidth, image.naturalHeight);
  ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    0,
    0,
    image.naturalWidth,
    image.naturalHeight,
    0,
    0,
    image.naturalWidth,
    image.naturalHeight
  );

  ctx.restore();

  return new Promise<{
    render: string;
    file: Blob | null;
  }>((resolve) => {
    canvas.toBlob((file) => {
      if (file != null) {
        const files: Blob | MediaSource = file;
        resolve({
          render: URL.createObjectURL(files),
          file: file,
        });
      }
    }, 'image/jpeg');
  });
}
```

Also, here I am attaching official demo of the react-image-crop.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-crop-demo-with-react-hooks-y831o

Comment: Yunnosch, I have updated my answer. Thank you for draw my attention.